# How to smoothly open panes across tabs in Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Our Firefox extension displays the top 25 Bing results in a side pane whenever someone searches from Google.  The results are scrubbed for duplicates.

The side pane is closed by default.  Only when someone views a Google results page does the side pane open.  The side pane automatically closes again when someone opens a non-Google page.

Unfortunately, the opening and closing of the pane is clunky.  The side pane is implemented as a vbox, and we set its collapsed property to "true" or "false" depending on the URL.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Download the extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/66587.

2) Search for "shoes" from Google.com or from the Firefox search bar.

3) Click one of the search results displayed in the Panabee side pane.  This opens the result in a new tab.

4) Click back and forth between the two tabs.  The opening/closing of the pane is clumsy.

Any suggestions on how to smooth the opening/closing of the pane?  Should we use something besides the collapsed property?  We tinkered with the hidden property, but it was no smoother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write the add on using [Jetpack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/), it automatically comes with [jquery](http://jquery.com). Since you are probably doing it sans Jetpack, I would include jquery with the add on and use the timing effects built in, such as [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Firefox uses XUL, so you can use any javascript framework to script things like the sidepane, since they are all part of the DOM.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  after reviewing firebug code, it doesn't appear they solve the problem with this approach.  i would like to emulate firebug if possible.  do you know how?

Comment: well, this unfortunately doesn't answer my question.  there are no other responses, though, and the bounty is ending soon.  i have no choice but to award you the points.